# Как распарсить xml?

Tags: xml, php, синтаксический-анализ

Привет, может случаем знает как распарсить XML

**https://hexillion.com/samples/WhoisXML/?query=google.com**

Comment: .

$xml = new \SimpelXMLElement($response);

Comment: А в примере можно?

Comment: В PHP есть библиотеки по работе с XML, стоит только открыть документацию. Там и SAX, и DOM, и SimpleXML, и XPath, выбор на любой вкус и цвет.

Comment: К сожалению я не очень силен в написание скриптов, поэтому и спросил пример. Я могу только подправить и тд.
Можно пример по моему вопросу?
Спасибо

Comment: Тогда вопрос в том, что вы хотите получить в результате парсинга?

Comment: Вывести информацию о доменах на страницах

Comment: Вот примерно такое-же как тут

http://centralops.net/asp/co/DomainCheck.vbs.asp

Только нужно ввести google.com

Вывести надо

<Domain>
<Name>HASHCODE.RU</Name>
<NameServer>ns1.nameself.com.</NameServer>
<NameServer>ns2.nameself.com.</NameServer>
<NameServerAddress/>
<NameServerAddress/>
<Status>REGISTERED</Status>
<Status>DELEGATED</Status>
<Status>VERIFIED</Status>
<CreatedDate>2010.11.05</CreatedDate>
<ExpiresDate>2014.11.05</ExpiresDate>
<Source>TCI</Source>
<DatabaseUpdatedDate>2014.06.27 20:16:33 MSK</DatabaseUpdatedDate>
</Domain>

Comment: @jikol, что именно из документа нужно?

Comment: Если не долго думая и на коленке, то можно попробовать так:

    $xml = simplexml_load_file('https://hexillion.com/samples/WhoisXML/?query=google.com');

    foreach ((array)$xml->QueryResult->WhoisRecord->Domain as $item) {
      if(is_array($item)){
        foreach($item as $subitem){
            echo $subitem."<br>";
        }
      }else{
        echo $item."<br>";
      }
    }

Еще можно почитать тут:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/x-simplexml/index.html

Comment: Вам на биржу, это не вопрос, а задание.

Answer (score 2):

правильный подход: делаем `simplexml_load_file` или `simplexml_load_string` (если, допустим, перекодировали xml в php, можем загрузить из строки)

если все прошло успешно, получаем xml-объект, c ним мы можем работать используя  [xpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath), путь  к элементам.

например:
создаем массив функций-обработчиков:
для каждого совпадающего xpath будет вызывана одна из этих функций

```
$xPaths=array(
    '/mynode/keywords/location[@keywords]'=>'', //ничего не делаем
    '/mynode/filters/filter'=>'filter', //вызовем функцию filter()
    '/mynode/someStrangeThing'=>'someStrangeThing', //функцию someStrangeThing()
    '/mynode/pid'=>'pid'  //pid()
);
```

далее работаем, например, так:

```
foreach ($xPaths as $path => $setting) {
        $pathResult = $xml->xpath($path);
        if ($pathResult) {
            if (!isset($foundPaths[$path])) {
                $foundPaths[$path] = array();
            }
            $func      = trim(preg_replace("/\W+/", "_", $path), "_");
            $tagResult = $func($pathResult); //вызываем функцию-обработчик
            if ($tagResult) {
                $foundPaths[$path][$oid] = $tagResult; // меняем элемент
            }
        }
    }
```

это мой пример, вам не обязательно использовать массивы функций и т.д., я просто хотел показать вам пример использования xpath, а не  дурацкого и слепого применения foreach для всех случаев

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ, это воспользоваться функцией `simplexml_load_file()`, которая возвращает объект `SimpleXMLElement` со структурой XML-файла

```
<?php
$url = 'https://hexillion.com/samples/WhoisXML/?query=google.com';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
echo '<pre>';
echo $xml->QueryResult->WhoisRecord->RawText;
```